# General Compound Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm looking after $E[S^3]$ where $S$ is a compound negative binomial.

Is there a general formula to calculate $E[S^3]$ like $E[S] = E[X]*E[N]$ ?

Comment: Do your compound negative negative binomial means $\displaystyle S = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $N$ follows a negative binomial distribution and $X$ follows ...

Comment: Yes, it does. I got it with a formula of the skewness of the compound negative binomial. Thank you!

Comment: Start with $$E(S^3\mid N)=E(X^3)N+3E(X^2)E(X)N(N-1)+E(X)^3N(N-1)(N-2)$$ then use the moments of $N$.